# OpenGL: skip every n quad in a GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP

Tags: c++, opengl

I am currently rendering a long path with a:

```
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 2000);
```

I pass my control points to a vbo like this:

```
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < lPoints.size() && i < rPoints.size(); ++i)
{
    if (i % 2 != 0)
    {
        vbo.AddData(&rPoints[i], sizeof(glm::vec3));
        vbo.AddData(&m_textCoords[i], sizeof(glm::vec2));
        vbo.AddData(&normal, sizeof(glm::vec3));
    }
    else
    {
        vbo.AddData(&lPoints[i], sizeof(glm::vec3));
        vbo.AddData(&m_textCoords[i], sizeof(glm::vec2));
        vbo.AddData(&normal, sizeof(glm::vec3));
    }
}
```

Using the image below as an example. My existing code succeeds in drawing all the quads together to form a path. But what I'd like to achieve is to draw one quad and skip one in a sequence. I.e. Draw triangles [v0, v1, v2] and [v2, v1, v3]. Skip [v2, v3, v4] and [v4, v3, v5].

[image: Triangle Strip]

Been hacking away at this for a while with no success. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To skip rendering of objects you have several ways:

A) Don't put them in VBO buffers.

B) Split the only `glDrawArrays` call into multiple calls, each one starting at a different position in the buffer (the second parameter of `glDrawArrays`).

C) Set a special color (or other property) for that primitives. If the shader meets this color *discard* the fragment (in a *fragment shader*) or don't emit vertices in a *geometry shader*.

D) As @Rabbid76 suggested, use indexed drawing and primitive restart.

Comment: I used method B and wrote `for (unsigned int i = 0; i < 2000; i = i+ 6) { glDrawyArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, i, 6); }`. It worked like a charm. Thanks

Comment: Bad for performance to issue so many draw calls.  Performance will be better with a single draw call.  Primitive Restart and indexing or restructuring the buffer is the right thing to do.  IF performance becomes a concern, shoot for a single draw call.

Comment: @Wyck The assertion *"Performance will be better with a single draw call"* had a chance 15 years ago. Nowadays you must show me some time measurements to convince me.

Comment: @Ripi2 "Minimize the Number of Draw Calls
Every API function call to draw geometry has an associated CPU cost, so minimizing the number of API calls and, in particular, minimizing the number of graphics state changes minimizes the amount of CPU work used for a given number of triangles rendered."  http://docs.nvidia.com/gameworks/index.html#developertools/desktop/nsight/appendix_a_optimizing.htm

Answer (score 2):

Rather than drawing triangle strip primitves (GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP), which necessarily implies connected topology, draw triangle primitives (GL_TRIANGLES).

You can't use the same vertex stream though.

Where you currently render GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP and pass vertices:

```
ABCDEFGHIJ ...
```

[image]

You'll now have to pass in GL_TRIANGLES and pass in vertices both triangles of each quad (every other quad in your case).

```
ABC CBD EFG GFH ...
```

Note the winding order because in a strip, every other triangle winds the other way.  (Tempting to send vertices in the order `ABC BCD EFG FGH ...` but that every second triangle would be counter-clockwise - opposite winding order.)

To use the same vertex stream, draw *indexed* primitives, and use an index buffer: `012 213 456 657 ...`